# What is the most appropriate solving method for ODE or PDE based ecosystem models in Python GEKKO?

Tags: python-3.x, python-xarray, gekko

I have been looking for a while, but could not find the answer to this specific question anywhere, sorry if it is a duplicate!

I have started to build a [python package](https://github.com/ben1post/phydra) based on the [xarray-simlab framework](https://github.com/benbovy/xarray-simlab/tree/master/xsimlab) with the goal to provide a modular toolbox for building reproducible and flexible marine ecosystem models. Xarray-simlab at the moment only supports explicit step-sizes to solve the model functions. In order to solve complex models more safely & efficiently, I have instead started using GEKKO as a solver backend, as the model syntax seems well suited. (Note: At the moment I will only need functionality to solve the model equations over time, but I would like to make use of GEKKO's optimization functionality to fit model parameters to field or lab data at later stages.)

The current prototype of the package creates a xsimlab process class that passes the GEKKO model instance
`m` to all sub-processes. Process classes that inherit the model instance initialize `m.SV`, `m.Param` or define `m.Intermediates` based on the processes added to the model & parameters (incl. SV dimensions) supplied at runtime. In the next step all initialized intermediates are accumulated to the affected state variables in `m.Equations`. Once successfully solved, GEKKO variables are repackaged into a xarray data structure, that includes relevant metadata and can be analysed further. The package prototype can solve basic models using IMODE=7, but I have come across one issue related to the time steps of that solver:

I was expecting functionality similar to scipy's odeint, with adaptive time step evaluation, but obviously this does not seem to be the case and instead it evaluates the model at the discrete time-steps supplied.

The package is still under heavy development, and there are plenty of features that I am still trying to improve, so below is a minimal code example of a simple chemostat model. The model describes a phytoplankton state variable growing on a nutrient in a simplified flow-through system. The nutrient flows in at a constant rate, and phytoplankton dies and is lost from the system at a constant rate:

```
import numpy as np
from gekko import GEKKO
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

m = GEKKO()    # create GEKKO model

halfsat_const = m.Param(0.1)
N0 = m.Param(1.)
inflow_rate = m.Param(0.1)
mortality_rate = m.Param(0.1)

N = m.SV(1)
P = m.SV(0.1)

t = np.arange(0,10,0.01)
m.time = t

# Growth under nutrient limitation is described via Monod / Michaelis-Menten kinetics
nutlim = m.Intermediate(N/(N+halfsat_const)*P)
N_influx = m.Intermediate(N0 * inflow_rate)
mortality = m.Intermediate(P * mortality_rate)

m.Equation(N.dt()==N_influx - nutlim)
m.Equation(P.dt()==nutlim - mortality)

m.options.IMODE = 7

m.solve(disp=False)

plt.plot(m.time, N, label='N')
plt.plot(m.time, P, label='P')
plt.legend()
```

This works perfectly for the supplied time-step, but e.g. `m.time = np.arange(0,10)` returns a nonsensical solution (two divergent lines reaching >1e7). Odeint has no problem solving it:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint

halfsat = 0.1
N0 = 1.
inflow = 0.1
mortality_rate = 0.1

def model(y,t):
    N,P = y
    nutlim = N/(N+halfsat)*P
    influx = N0 * inflow
    mortality = P * mortality_rate
    
    dNdt = influx - nutlim
    dPdt = nutlim - mortality
    return [dNdt, dPdt]

model_time = np.arange(0,10)
out = odeint(model,[1,0.1],model_time)

plt.plot(model_time,out[:,0], label='N')
plt.plot(model_time,out[:,1], label='P')
plt.legend()
```

The models I am building with my package can get relatively complex, with hundreds of state variables, and a much larger number of interactions, yielding highly non-linear results. I am not sure how I can be sure that my supplied time step is appropriate, since smaller time steps significantly increase computational time.

Is there a solver included with GEKKO (or compatible with the GEKKO model syntax) that provides a similar solver to odeint with adaptive step size? Or is there another approach that is better suited to deal with ecological models based on ODEs (or spatially-discretized PDE systems)?

Any help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to increase the number of nodes per segment with:

```py
m.options.NODES = 3
```

This gives a more accurate solution because a higher order collocation method is used. In this case the time points [0,1,2,...9,10] are too coarse for an accurate solution but [0,0.5,1,...9.5,10] works fine.

Additionally, setting the lower boundary for the state variables to zero via `m.SV(lb=0)` will improve solving stability. This is a basic assumption of ecosystem models, that components tracked by e.g. biomass would not be negative.

[image: Gekko and ODEINT solutions]

I typically recommend a grid independence test where you reduce the step size until the solution doesn't change or compare with an adaptive step-size solver such as ODEINT. Gekko does do adaptive step sizes for `IMODE=7` but only when the solver fails on a step. It is up to the user to decide the discretization. The strength of Gekko is in optimization and an adaptive step size in optimization requires a multi-level strategy that can be very slow. However, there has been [recent progress](https://aiche.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/aic.16584). If you'd like to have an adaptive step size with `IMODE=7` and error checking, please consider a [feature request](https://github.com/BYU-PRISM/GEKKO/issues).

```py
import numpy as np
from gekko import GEKKO
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

m = GEKKO(remote=False)    # create GEKKO model

halfsat_const = m.Param(0.1)
N0 = m.Param(1.)
inflow_rate = m.Param(0.1)
mortality_rate = m.Param(0.1)

N = m.SV(1, lb=0)
P = m.SV(0.1, lb=0)

t = np.arange(0,10,0.2)
m.time = t

# Growth under nutrient limitation is described via Monod / Michaelis-Menten kinetics
nutlim = m.Intermediate(N/(N+halfsat_const)*P)
N_influx = m.Intermediate(N0 * inflow_rate)
mortality = m.Intermediate(P * mortality_rate)

m.Equation(N.dt()==N_influx - nutlim)
m.Equation(P.dt()==nutlim - mortality)

m.options.NODES = 3
m.options.IMODE = 7

m.solve(disp=False)



halfsat = 0.1
N0 = 1.
inflow = 0.1
mortality_rate = 0.1

def model(y,t):
    N,P = y
    nutlim = N/(N+halfsat)*P
    influx = N0 * inflow
    mortality = P * mortality_rate
    
    dNdt = influx - nutlim
    dPdt = nutlim - mortality
    return [dNdt, dPdt]

model_time = np.arange(0,10)
out = odeint(model,[1,0.1],model_time)

plt.plot(model_time,out[:,0], 'ro', label='N ODEINT')
plt.plot(model_time,out[:,1], 'bx', label='P ODEINT')

plt.plot(m.time, N, 'r--', label='N Gekko')
plt.plot(m.time, P, 'b--', label='P Gekko')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick reply and explanation! For my application, the adaptive step size solver would not require any optimization capabilities, it is simply for model exploration, before settling on a structure to optimize. I will add a feature request. 

I have one follow-up question: Is there a recommended methodology to do a grid independence test for more complex models (i.e. is there some reliable way to automate it outside GEKKO) or would you rather recommend manually decreasing time steps and comparing output?

Comment: The easiest way to do the grid independence study is to decrease the step size by 2x until there is no additional change. You can also use a non-uniform grid such as `m.time=[0,0.01,0.02,0.04,0.1,0.2,0.4,1.0,....]` if there are fast dynamics that you'd like to capture at the beginning or another part of your simulation. One approach is to add more grid points where the gradients are high. Thanks for adding an issue in the GEKKO repository on GitHub.

Comment: Here is the Gekko enhancement request for those who would like to follow the development: https://github.com/BYU-PRISM/GEKKO/issues/88

Comment: Thank you very much! I just found that setting the lower boundary `m.SV(lb=0)` for all state variables greatly improves the stability when solving with large time steps and returns a `Solution Not Found` error for when it eventually fails to solve. This of course makes a lot of sense in ecological models! Perhaps that could be included in your answer above? 

Also, would the adaptive time-step solver be a complicated addition to GEKKO / apm or could this be achieved relatively easily? I would be very happy to help with the feature development, if I can.

Comment: I proposed the suggested edit to your answer, thank you for your help!

Comment: Thanks for adding to the post - the lower bound is an important addition.